# SwiftUI How to Navigate to Multiple Possible Views Depending on Conditional?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Creating a Study App, if I click on the tabs Cue Card, Multiple Choice Test, or Practice Test I want to navigate to three different views possibly but I want to do that all from one Tab View where I have a navigationLink that is a variable or something that depends on whether I clicked the tab Cue Card, Multiple Choice Test, or Practice Test.

I also already tried doing this in the enum method from the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGiFR0IZCz4&t=53s but could not figure it out.

[image]

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct SelectionView: View {
    
var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        VStack {
            TabsView(selection: "Cue Cards")
            TabsView(selection: "Multiple Choice")
            TabsView(selection: "Practice Test")
            

        }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        
    }
    
    
}





struct SelectionView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            SelectionView().previewDevice("iPhone 8")
            SelectionView().previewDevice("iPhone 11 Pro")
            SelectionView().previewDevice("iPhone 11 Pro Max")
            
        }
    }
   }
}
import SwiftUI


struct TabsView: View {

@State private var isActive = false
 var selection = ""

var body: some View {

    VStack{
        //WANT CUECARDCATEGORYVIEW() TO BE A VARIABLE OR SOMETHING THAT CAN 
 LEAD TO CUE CARD VIEW, MULTIPLE CHOICE TEST VIEW, OR PRACTICE TEST VIEW.
        NavigationLink(destination: CueCardCategoryView(), isActive: 
$isActive)
        {
            Button(action: {isActive = true }) {
                HStack{
                    Text("\(selection)")
                        .font(.system(size: 28, weight: .semibold))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }.buttonStyle(PrimaryButtonStyle(fillColor: .primaryButton))
        
    }.padding(15)
}

}

struct TabsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    NavigationView{
        TabsView()
    }.environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
    .environment(\.colorScheme, .light)
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you add your code as *code* to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

**SelectionView**

```
enum TabSelection {
    case cueCards, multipleChoice, practiceTest
}

struct SelectionView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                TabsView(title: "Cue Card", selection: .cueCards)
                TabsView(title: "Multiple Choice", selection: .multipleChoice)
                TabsView(title: "Practice Test", selection: .practiceTest)
                
            }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        }
    }
    
    
    struct SelectionView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            Group {
                SelectionView().previewDevice("iPhone 8")
                SelectionView().previewDevice("iPhone 11 Pro")
                SelectionView().previewDevice("iPhone 11 Pro Max")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Tabs View**

```
import SwiftUI


struct TabsView: View {
    @State private var isActive = false
    var title: String
    var selection: TabSelection
    
    var body: some View {
        
        switch selection {
        case .cueCards:
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("My Custom View 1"), isActive: $isActive, label: {
                HStack{
                    Text(title)
                        .font(.system(size: 28, weight: .semibold))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    Spacer()
                }
            })
        case .multipleChoice:
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("My Custom View 2"), isActive: $isActive, label: {
                HStack{
                    Text(title)
                        .font(.system(size: 28, weight: .semibold))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    Spacer()
                }
            })
        case .practiceTest:
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("My Custom View 3"), isActive: $isActive, label: {
                HStack{
                    Text(title)
                        .font(.system(size: 28, weight: .semibold))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    Spacer()
                }
            })
        }
    }
}


struct TabsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView{
            TabsView(title: "Cue Card", selection: .cueCards)
        }.environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
        .environment(\.colorScheme, .light)
    }
}
```

Replace the Text("My Custom View 1") / 2 / 3 with your destination views.

Comment: That was perfect! Exactly what I wanted. Thank You! Quick question: there's an enum TabSelection declared in the Selection class, but you set var selection TabSelection in the TabsView. Enums are readable between all files, if declared in one? (I'm very new to coding. I'm thinkin of it like a class/struct where you'd have to declare it in another class to use it's functions).

Comment: The answer is no. You need to declare them in each view you want to use. And we do this in TabsView also but in a slightly different way. This is what we do when we create a new TabsView inside SelectionView.

For example, when we create this TabsView: 
TabsView(title: "Cue Card", selection: .cueCards)
we actually declare the "var selection" in TabsView with the value ".cueCards"